# powershell try-catch doesn't capture invoke-sqlcmd error

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a function that I pass a server name to, then select some data from that server and insert it into a table on a centralized server.  The list of servers is generated from a centralized server that isn't always up to date, and I would like for it to keep processing and log any errors that occur.  However, my try-catch block doesn't seem to capture any errors.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610593/powershell-try-catch-invoke-sqlcmd) and tried that, and I still can't capture the errors.  Here's a generic version of my function:

```
function Get-QueryData
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
        param 
        (
            [string] $server
        )

     $QuerySelect = "select * from dbo.Table"

    try
{
$results = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server `
        -Database TheDatabase `
        -Query $QuerySelect `
        -QueryTimeout 20 `
        -OutputSqlErrors $True `
        -ConnectionTimeout 5 `
        -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch
{
    #to-do: log error
    Write Host "    An error occurred trying to get query info"
}
 #  remaining function inserts into central server, this part doesn't fail
 #  unless the first part fails
}
```

The error I get:

> Invoke-Sqlcmd: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred
>   while establishing a connection to SQL Server... CategoryInfo:
>   InvalidOperations (:) [Invoke-SqlCmd] SqlException
>   FullQualifiedErrorId :
>   SqlExecutionError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Powershell.GetScriptCommand

---

The reason I'm getting this error is that the server was stood up, and then had to be rebuilt, but it was already added to our central management server.  I can't rely on this being cleaned up right away so I need the powershell to log the error and keep moving.

---

Output from $PsVersionTable.PSVersion

Major - 5

Minor - 1

Build - 14409

Revision - 1012

Comment: Appears to be a bug with some versions of the SQLPS module.  I'd recommend trying with the newer [`SqlServer` PowerShell module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SqlServer/21.0.17240) that replaces it.  That will not work if you're trying to use PowerShell from SQL Agent, however.

Comment: If nothing works or you have to use the installed SQLPS module, then I'd fall back on the .Net SqlClient methods.

Comment: i'm an idiot and was copying an out dated version of my code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm an idiot and I was copying from an outdated copy.  My NEW version that reflects the changes made per the link in my question works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

- In the `Try{}` set `$flag=$True`
- In the `Try{}` remove the $results variable from the get-sqlcmd
- In the `Catch{}` set `$flag=$false`
- Add a `finally{}` that checks for the flag
- In the `Finally{}` add an `if(!x){y}else{z}`
- In the `Finally{if(!x){y}else{z}}`
- if `$flag` is `$false` write to log and exit
- if `$flag` is `$true` do your work and then write to log

I've provided `[sting]$message >> $targetFile` for simple logging. There are way better ways to do logging and I've used this example only as an simple example and not a suggestion.

```
function Get-QueryData 
{
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [string] $server
)
$QuerySelect = "select * from dbo.Table"
try
{
    $flag = $true
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server `
        -Database TheDatabase `
        -Query $QuerySelect `
        -QueryTimeout 20 `
        -OutputSqlErrors $True `
        -ConnectionTimeout 5 `
        -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch
{
    $flag = $false
    #to-do: log error with $_ which contains the error object
    Write-Host "An error occurred trying to get query info"
    $errorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
}
finaly
{
    # log errors if flag false
    if (!$flag){
        "[$(get-date)] - $errorMessage" >> `
            $(some target accessible path to a writable file)
        #Stop the function and return an exit code of 1
        Return 1            
    } else {
        #  remaining function inserts into central server
        "[$(get-date)] - Short Meaningful Success Message" >> `
            $(some target accessible path to a writable file)          
    }
}
}
```